# Unpack variadic template parameter pack into function signature

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I've created class for dispatching and handling events in a small library. My goal is to make it as easy as possible to use, avoiding macro pollution. Events are registered in compile time, listeners are subscribing from events in runtime. Both are identified by enums in `Resource` namespace. `Pack` is storage for variadic template parameters. `EventInfo` is way to tell what parameters we are going to use in `Listener` and `Event`. Code:

```
namespace Resource 
{
    enum class Resource::EventId;
    enum class Resource::ListenerId;
}

template< class EventId, EventId id >
struct EventInfo;

template< class... Args >
struct Pack
{
};

template< class ListenerId_, class... EventData >
struct Listener
{
    using ListenerId = ListenerId_;

    ListenerId Id = ListenerId::Undefined;
    bool IsEnabled = false;
    std::function< void( EventData... ) > Callback = nullptr;
};

template< class ListenerId_, class... EventData >
struct EventInfoHelper
{
    using Data = Pack< EventData... >;
    using Listener = typename Listener< ListenerId_, EventData... >;
    using ListenerId = typename Listener::ListenerId;
};

#define REGISTER_EVENT_W_ARGS( NAME, ... ) \
template<> \
struct EventInfo< Resource::EventId, Resource::EventId::NAME > \
{ \
public: \
    using Hlpr = EventInfoHelper< Resource::ListenerId, __VA_ARGS__ >; \
    using Data = Hlpr::Data; \
    using Listener = Hlpr::Listener; \
    using ListenerId = Hlpr::ListenerId; \
};

REGISTER_EVENT_W_ARGS( OnUpdate, const sf::Time& );
// ... macro undef here

template< class Id, Id id >
class Event
{
public:
    using Data = typename EventInfo< Id, id >::Data;
    using Listener = typename EventInfo< Id, id >::Listener;
    using ListenerId = typename EventInfo< Id, id >::ListenerId;

    template< class... DataUnpacked, class = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same< Pack< DataUnpacked... >, Data >::value > >
    static void Dispatch( DataUnpacked... data )
    {
        for( auto& listener : m_listeners )
        {
            CHECK( listener.Id != ListenerId::Undefined );
            if( listener.IsEnabled )
            {
                CHECK( listener.Callback != nullptr );
                listener.Callback( data... );
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
private:
    static std::vector< Listener > m_listeners;
};
```

Current use case:

```
Event< Resource::EventId, Resource::EventId::OnUpdate >::Dispatch< const sf::Time& >( dt );
```

Desired (parameter deduction from `EventInfo::Data`):

```
Event< Resource::EventId, Resource::EventId::OnUpdate >::Dispatch( dt );
```

Question is how to implement `Dispatch` with parameters registered in `EventInfo::Data` as `Pack< Args... >` arguments?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Barry: he wants to put the types coded into the type `Pack<T1, T2, ...>` to a function signature: `Dispatch(T1 t1, T2 t2, ...)`.

Comment: Not clear to me either. Maybe write the code with 1,2 and 3 types in the variadic type parameter list and then we can see howto generalize that to any number of template arguments. In any case I expect your example code to compile, otherwise I will not look into it.

Comment: Note in C++17 you can usually replace `template <class T, T Value>` with `template <auto Value>`.

Comment: How many events does your system have?  What utility is there in hetrogenous events sharing one storage location?  Why use enums for event ids, why not the actual event objects?  Why `Event< Resource::EventId, Resource::EventId::OnUpdate >::Dispatch` instead of `Event::OnUpdate::Dispatch`?

Answer (score 1):

the code you provided wasn't complete so i couldn't integrate the solution in your example.

you can use a base class to extract the parameter pack from Pack<...> and expand it in a function in the base class

```
template<typename ...>
class Pack {};

template<typename>
class test_base;

template<typename ... Args>
class test_base<Pack<Args...>> {
    public:
    void Dispatcher(Args... args) {
        //implemntation
    }
};

template<typename ... Args>
class test : public test_base<Pack<Args...>> {
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand (and I can try to compile because your example is too incomplete) but seems to me that you can pass through an additional typename template parameter, with a default value, and a specialization.

I mean... something as

```
template <typename Id, Id id, typename = typename EventInfo<Id, id>::Data>
class Event;

template <typename Id, Id id, typename ... DataUnpacked>
class Event<Id, id, Pack<DataUnpacked...>>
 {
   // ...

   public:
      static void Dispatch (DataUnpacked ... data)
       {
         // ...
       }
 };
```

This way, when you create a variable `Event<EventId, EventId::someId>`, it's defaulted to `Event<EventId, EventId::someId, typename EventInfo<EventId, EventId::someId>::Data>` that is `Event<EventId, EventId::someId, Pack<Ts...>>` for some `Ts...` variadic list.

The specialization permit to intercept that `Ts...` list (as `DataUnpacked...`, following your example) and use it in the `Dispatch()` signature.

Off Topic Suggestion: as observed by aschepler, you tagged C++17 so you can use `auto` template values; so the code can be simply

```
template <auto id, typename = typename EventInfo<id>::Data>
class Event;

template <auto id, typename ... DataUnpacked>
class Event<id, Pack<DataUnpacked...>>
 {
   // ...

   public:
      static void Dispatch (DataUnpacked ... data)
       {
         // ...
       }
 };
```

if also `EventInfo` receive an `auto id`.